# ggplot library() error R version 3.1.3

Tags: r, ggplot2

I installed ggplot2 using install.packages() function. It gets installed properly and shows in the Packages pan. However, when I run library(ggplot2), I get the following error:

`library("ggplot2", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")`

*Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘digest’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’*

What is going on here? Can somebody help, please?

Comment: Can you just run `library(digest)`? Can you confirm that package is installed via `installed.packages()`? Is it installed to a different LibPath?

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. Package was installed via `installed.packages()`. Tried `library(digest)` but it didn't work. Then, I removed both R and RStudio and re-installed them. That seems to have done the trick. Thanks @peter and @PeterSmith.