# Error When Using AppliedPredictiveModeling Package

Tags: r

When using R Studio, I install the `AppliedPredictiveModeling` package and call it up with the `library()` command. When I do, this happens:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘AppliedPredictiveModeling’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): DLL ‘CORElearn’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?

I installed the `CORElearn` package and then used the `library(CORElearn)` command and everything seems fine. I then ran the command `library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)` and get the same error message.

What do I need to do?

Comment: maybe [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dll-not-found-maybe-not-installed-for-this-architecture/54734/16) is helpful? I would try: (1) start a new R session; (2) `install.packages("CORElearn", dependencies=TRUE)`; (3) `install.packages("AppliedPredictiveModeling", dependencies=TRUE)`; (4) `library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)`  (in that order!) and see if it helps

Comment: [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359089/ggplot-library-error-r-version-3-1-3) reinstalled R and RStudio. That seems a little extreme.

Comment: @BenBolker I get the same error. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘AppliedPredictiveModeling’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL ‘CORElearn’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture? I am at a loss as to what to do.